# Netbeans - Build targetting JDK 6 but run using Java 7 JRE

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm working on a project where I need to build against JDK 1.6 but I would like to test it against both Java 1.6 and 1.7 - I have both Java 1.6 and 1.7 JDKs installed.

I know I can create a new Java Platform for each but that would result in the project being built against JDK 1.6/1.7 as well - I only want it run against both. Is there an easy way to tell Netbeans to build against my JDK 1.6 Platform but run using my Java 1.7 JRE. Or even if there is an option for using an external JRE to run the project with I could make it work.

Comment: you mean you want to compile using `JDK6` and want to run it using `JDK 7` ?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be compiled via JDK6 but I want to test running it against Java 6 and Java 7 to make sure there aren't any changes in operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the project properties by right clicking on the left hand pane

**Build->Compiling**

on lower side you will see **Additional Compiler options**

give the params as `-target 6` and this will compile you code according to `JDK 6` and when you will run the program it will run it using `JRE 7`.

Comment: And I assume I would set my Java Platform to be JDK7 then?

Comment: exactly... you will have to set platform to `JDK 7`

Comment: if say so,.. then @kaysush... if i want the target become JDK 5, i should write -target 5 is that true?